# what classes of modules admit finite free resolutions?

Tags: commutative-algebra

As i understand, finitely generated graded modules over Noetherian graded rings admit a finite free resolution (FFR). What are other classes of modules that admit a FFR? How about finitely generated modules over local Noetherian rings?

Comment: Finite free resolutions admit all modules that have finite projective dimension. (If this means to have also finite rank free modules, then just add the noetherian property to the module>) Maybe you want to ask for "minimal" free resolutions.

Comment: @YACP: Minimal free resolutions need not be finite, though, correct?

Comment: The minimal free resolution gives exactly the projective dimension of the module.

Comment: @YACP: So far i know only about minimal free resolutions of modules over local rings (paragraph 1.3 from Bruns and Herzog), in which case i can see that the minimal free resolution gives the projective dimension. Does the book treat MFR for modules over non-local rings as well?

Comment: No, because these don't exist.

Comment: @YACP: That's useful to know. Is the following correct: i) MFRs exist for graded modules over graded Noetherian rings ii) for a graded module over a graded Noetherian ring the MFR need not be finite

Comment: i) No. The graded ring has to be *local, that is, to have only one homogeneous maximal ideal. ii) Yes, if such a resolution there exists.

Comment: @YACP: Great, things are clearer now. I could accept all your comments as an answer.